# @DateTimeFormat com dia do horário de verão com erro

Tags: java, jpa, spring, datetime

Estou tendo um problema em converter data do dia 15/10/2017 (início do horário de verão)

Meu mapeamento está assim:

```
@Column(nullable = false)
@NotNull
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date dataVisita;
```

Ao processar o request, eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> Failed To Convert Property Value Of Type Java.Lang.String To Required
>   Type Java.Util.Date For Property DataVisita; Nested Exception Is
>   Org.Springframework.Core.Convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed To
>   Convert From Type Java.Lang.String To Type @Javax.Persistence.Column
>   @Javax.Validation.Constraints.NotNull
>   @Org.Springframework.Format.Annotation.DateTimeFormat Java.Util.Date
>   For Value 15/10/2017; Nested Exception Is
>   Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot Parse "15/10/2017": Illegal
>   Instant Due To Time Zone Offset Transition (America/Sao_Paulo)

Entendo que o erro me informa que a data 15/10/2017 00:00:00 não existe. O que eu queria que a aplicação efetuasse era a transformação automática para 15/10/2017 01:00:00

Existe alguma forma de sobrescrever a implementação de @DateTimeFormat para reimplementar o parse?

Obrigado

Answer (score -1):

I've found an alternate solution that solves this problem:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8669

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);

    // true passed to CustomDateEditor constructor means convert empty String to null
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
}
```

Adding this to my controller, reseting the lenient and adding the CustomEditor.